# How to redirect a link to a new link?

Tags: url-rewriting, redirect, apache

I am about to change the slug for my page's permalink. Since I dont want to loose the traffic, i would like to redirect the visitors to the new more SEo friendly link.

Can I achieve this with the mod_rewrite? (I use Apache on Ubuntu)

Or any other easier alternative? (I prefer not using any plugin if possible)

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go with the easiest alternative of all: *do nothing*.

No, really: WordPress itself handles redirects for renamed Post Titles.

#### Edit

Apparently, the retention of `_wp_old_slug` [only happens for *non-hierarchical* objects](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/post.php#L4118).

So, since Pages are hierarchical, they don't get to enjoy the auto-magic slug redirection.

Therefore, for static Pages or other hierarchical post objects, I would recommend using a 301 Redirect Plugin. [There are several to choose from](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=301%20redirect&sort=).

Comment: Sorry, thats not a post. Its a page. I don't think doing nothing would work, as I have tried. Thanks

Comment: As far as WordPress is concerned, a blog post is the same as a page. They're both *posts*, just with different post *types*.

Comment: I just have changed the slug of my permalink from www.example.com/products to www.example.com/Banana. After saving it www.example.com/products doesn't work any longer. I was expecting the visitor would be redirected to www.example.com/Banana instead.

Comment: Did you change the slug, or just the title?

Comment: See updated answer. `_wp_old_slug` is only retained for *non-hierarchical* post objects.

Comment: Thats true. I prefer not using a plugin though. I found a way: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-do-i-make-a-page-redirect-to-my-static-website  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've changed permalinks on sites before and I was scared it was going to ruin things, but as Chip stated, doing nothing worked. WordPress took care of it for me. No action taken on my part and all the links worked just fine.

Mark Jaquith created a plugin to help with this, but on the plugin page he explains that the plugin isn't needed beyond WP 2.1 because the functionality is part of the core now. (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirect-old-slugs/)